# Securing server code of my phonegap application from other CORS request

Tags: php, android, angularjs, codeigniter, cordova

I have a phonegap app which interacts with my php code on the server. Now in order to allow my angular js code to get data from server I have included the following  headers in my php code at the server.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding,x-requested-with");
```

Now I can easily get the required data from my server to my app but It seems any one from any platform can make hits to that url and get data . Is it possible to only allow my phonegap app to have access to the methods on the server and not to any other app or code.I am using the code igniter framework on my server.

How to do this in phonegap ?

Comment: you can put the name of the domain for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin attribute e.g `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.mydomain.com`. To allow **subdomains** you can change it to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.mydomain.com`. Also you can **whitelist** the domains so that the phonegap app can only access the requiste domains

Comment: Suppose I open a browser and simply type the url of my server which my android app is supposed to hit . Then my android app should get access but the other guy should be rejected even though both are accessing the same url . Will your technique which you have mentioned above do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use API token.

Essentially, your request is going to contain your API token or key as a part of the request payload.

On the server, you check that the token matches with what is a valid token.

If matches allow it otherwise decline the request

Comment: Can you direct me to a blog or code where I can Do some R and D on this API token thing coz I really dont know what  it means or How to do that in codeigniter and phonegap.

Comment: You can do one thing create a hardcoded key(with or without encryption)  into your mobile application and embed it with request you send to server on the server side extract the original key and match it with the key you stored in server(in database or in encrypted form as a variable) if both key matches expose your api otherwise just throw error.
Now only your mobile user can access your api but still it's just a alternative not full proof method.